# Can I install my own certificate in my shop?

Tags: shopify

Based on the documentation I've found I think the answer is unfortunately no but I thought I'd ask here to be sure.  We're moving our shop to a custom domain and would like the whole site (not just the checkout experience) to be SSL.  Is there any way to install our own cert to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not yet possible to use your own SSL cert with Shopify. You do however have SSL/https support for your entire site when using the https://YOUR-STORE.myshopify.com set of URLs.

Comment: Shopify only allows for SSL on checkout pages, not on your entire custom domain. Where are you getting this info?

Comment: My bad – I’ve clarified my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the cost for the certificate and the cpu and network costs of running the whole site under https I don't see why you can't.  Here's a post on this topic with more information: [Using SSL Across Entire Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515283/using-ssl-across-entire-site)

Comment: Seems like you can't because Shopify doesn't let you install a certificate you buy for your custom domain.  This would be a great feature to add because the only options today are no SSL or SSL with a cert that throws a browser error because it's not issued for your shop's custom domain.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were getting off Shopify.

Comment: Well, this is one reason we will probably have to eventually because we really should be serving every page via SSL in order to protect our users from things like session hijacking.  Fortunately the checkout flow is protected so I think we can live with it for now.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Shopify is a hosted platform. Buying an SSL certificate for your shop is a waste of money. You cannot use it. Your domain name has zero impact on this.